# Kubernetes set machine type in google console

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am new to kubernetes. It is possible to set the machine types of the nodes?
Is this possible via the normal UI backend or only via API?

Comment: Or maybe you can use/create a GKE (Google Kubernetes) in Autopilot mode, where you wont need to care about neither about node pools, nodes, nor their machine type, in a pay per pod fashion rather  than pay per node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to set the machine type either via UI or API.

gcloud example:

```
gcloud container clusters create my-gke --zone us-central1-c --num-nodes=1 --machine-type=e2-small
```

UI:

[image]